# Same button, different text. selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two types of buttons, with the same classes, ids etc, but two things are different. The action they do, and the text. One has "invite" text, the other one "message". I want to do something when it's "invite" and something else when it's "message". Do you know what I have to use? An if? Or I have to use `webDriverWait`?

This is HTML code.

```
<button aria-label="Invite" class="button m5"> Invite </button>
```

or

```
<button aria-label="Message" class="button m5"> Message </button>
```

I tried something like this and doesn't work. Do you have an idea why?

```
buttons=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button m5")
for but in (buttons):
fetch_text=but.text
if "Invite" in fetch_text:
###do somethin
else: ###do somethin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the className is same for both the elements, you can first fetch the text using the className and then put the if condition on the text and then operate accordingly.

For example, in your case, it would be like:

```
fetch_element_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button m5").text

if "Invite" in fetch_element_text:
     # Operate according to the Invite button 

elif "Message" in fetch_element_text:
     # Operate according to the Message button
```

**Updated Answer**:
As per your updated question, please try the below xpath for fetching the elements in the loop:

```
buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='button m5']")
print(len(buttons))
for button in buttons:
    fetch_element_text = button.text
```

And now you can put the same if else condition as it mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks!! Works perfectly!!

Comment: Can you check my code again? I updated it and for this context, and doesn't work.. Have an idea why?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ? And is there any reason you are using a loop to get the text ?

Comment: If there is only one text that you need to fetch, then you dont need to use the loop, as there might be a chance that  there are multiple buttons on the same with the same class name and those are then getting updated in your element because of the loop you are using.

Comment: I am using a loop because I have a list of buttons. Right now I am running the code and I wait to get the error when it finds "invite" button.

Comment: But you should not use classname in loop, you need to use xpath in that case. However as per your case, you can just fetch the element without using loop as mentioned in my answer. Please try that.

Comment: As you are using a loop to fetch the elements, i have updated my answer and you can fetch the elements using xpath and then put the condition on the texts you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You could locate each button via [xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath):

```
invite = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Invite']")
print(invite.text)   # Invite
message = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Message']")
print(message.text)  # Message
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `find_elements_by_class_name` to search multiple elements.Please use either `xpath` or `CssSelector`

```
buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='button m5']")
print(len(buttons))
for button in buttons:
    fetch_text = button.text
    if "Invite" in fetch_text:
      print("Invite Button")
    else:
      print("Massage Button")
```

OR

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.m5")
print(len(buttons))
for button in buttons:
   fetch_text = button.text
   if "Invite" in fetch_text:
      print("Invite Button")
   else:
      print("Massage Button")
```